# issue while importing org.springframework.web : cannot resolve symbol 'web'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have an issue while importing `org.springframework.web` in my controller. I don't know what happened.

I have imported this project in `intellij` and build this with `maven`. 
I also add spring in my project structure. So I let maven includes all the necessary libraries and generates the `pom.xml`.

Actually, I am trying to build a rest api in JEE.

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>fr.university.rouen</groupId>
<artifactId>JEE</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>JEE Maven Webapp</name>
<!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
<url>http://www.example.com</url>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  <spring.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <finalName>JEE</finalName>
  <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

and here is my controller:

```
package src.main.controllers;

import Database.src.entities.UserEntity;
import Database.src.repository.classes.UserRepository;
import factory.DataBaseSessionFactory;
import main.utils.PasswordSaltAndHash;
import main.utils.XMLObjects.LoginXMLObject;
import main.utils.XMLObjects.RegisterXMLObject;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*; // Get error : cannot resolved symbol 'web'
import JEE.Database.src.repository.interfaces.IUserRepository;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@RestController
class UserController {
    private final Pattern EMAIL_REGEX = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    private final Pattern PASSWORD_REGEX = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9]{8,16}$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    private IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public UserController() {
        _userRepository = new UserRepository();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String register(@RequestBody String content) {
        RegisterXMLObject register = RegisterXMLObject.XMLToRegister(content);
        if (register.getFirstName() == null || register.getFirstName().isEmpty()
                || register.getLastName() == null || register.getLastName().isEmpty()
                || register.getEmail() == null || register.getEmail().isEmpty()
                || register.getPassword() == null || register.getPassword().isEmpty()
                || register.getPasswordConfirm() == null || register.getPasswordConfirm().isEmpty()) {
            return "All fields are required !";
        }

        Matcher matcher2 = PASSWORD_REGEX.matcher(register.getPassword());
        if (!matcher2.matches()) {
            return "Password is not valid!";
        }

        Matcher matcher1 = EMAIL_REGEX.matcher(register.getEmail());
        if (!matcher1.matches()) {
            return "Email address is not valid!";
        }

        if (!register.getPassword().equals(register.getPasswordConfirm())) {
            return "The two passwords are not equal!";
        }
        final Session session = DataBaseSessionFactory.getSession();

        UserEntity user = _userRepository.GetByEmail(register.getEmail(), session);
        if (user != null) {
            session.close();
            return "This email address is already used!";
        }

        byte[] salt = new String(PasswordSaltAndHash.getNextSalt()).getBytes();
        byte[] hash = new String(PasswordSaltAndHash.hash(register.getPassword().toCharArray(), salt)).getBytes();

        UserEntity entity = new UserEntity();
        entity.setFirstname(register.getFirstName());
        entity.setLastname(register.getLastName());
        entity.setEmail(register.getEmail());
        entity.setPasswordHash(new String(hash));
        entity.setPasswordSalt(new String(salt));

        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        _userRepository.Add(entity, session);
        tx.commit();

        session.close();

        return "User created!";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@RequestBody String content) {
        LoginXMLObject login = LoginXMLObject.XMLToLogin(content);

        if (login.getLogin() == null || login.getLogin().isEmpty()
                || login.getPassword() == null || login.getPassword().isEmpty()) {
            return "All fields are required!";
        }

        final Session session = DataBaseSessionFactory.getSession();

        UserEntity user = _userRepository.GetByEmail(login.getLogin(), session);
        if (user == null) {
            session.close();
            return "This user doesn't exists!";
        }

        byte[] hash = new String(PasswordSaltAndHash.hash(login.getPassword().toCharArray(),
                user.getPasswordSalt().getBytes())).getBytes();
        if (!new String(hash).equals(user.getPasswordHash())) {
            session.close();
            return "Password is not valid!";
        }

        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        byte[] token = new String(PasswordSaltAndHash.getNextSalt()).getBytes();
        user.setToken(new String(token));
        tx.commit();

        session.close();
        return user.getToken();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String logout(@RequestBody String content) {
        final Session session = DataBaseSessionFactory.getSession();

        UserEntity user = _userRepository.GetByToken(content, session);
        if (user == null) {
            session.close();
            return "This user doesn't exists!";
        }

        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        user.setToken("");
        tx.commit();

        session.close();
        return "User disconnected";
    }
}
```

Any help is welcomed

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*; : cannot resolve symbol 'web'

Comment: please update your question with error stack trace.

Comment: Done, sorry for the inconvenance